# Solana Close program

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, close

I wan to close a solana program. I have to check what public key is used to close the program, how can I do that. I have multiple file wallet private keys but i do not know which belongs to it. Is there any way to check. Also if yes how can I do that? I have solana keys in my desktop in my-solana-wallet file but when i go there and run command like `solana program show --programs` or `solana program show --buffers` but i do not find any program. Is here a way to successfully close the program?

Comment: Also `solana program close <programId> showing `Error: Program authority None does not match Some<UnknownAddress>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to get all programs owned by a public key. You can enter your file keypair public keys and fetch all programs owned by it and then close it using CLI.

```
const pubKeyToPrograms = async (publicKey: string) => {
  const connection = new web3.Connection(
    "rpc_url"
  );

  const accounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(
    new web3.PublicKey("BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111"),
    {
      dataSlice: {
        offset: 4 + 8 + 1 + 32,
        length: 0,
      },
      filters: [
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 0,
            bytes: anchor.utils.bytes.bs58.encode([3, 0, 0, 0]),
          },
        },

        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 4 + 8,
            bytes: anchor.utils.bytes.bs58.encode([1]),
          },
        },

        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 4 + 8 + 1,
            bytes: new web3.PublicKey(
              publicKey
            ).toBase58(),
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  );
  console.log("RESULTS: ", accounts);
};

await pubKeyToPrograms("your_pubkey");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right command with `solana program show --buffers / --programs`. If you have multiple file-system wallets, you'll likely need to try each one to see which has open programs by using the `-k` flag, ie:

```
solana program show --buffers -k my_file_system_wallet.json
```

And then to close all buffers, you can run:

```
solana program close --buffers -k my_file_system_wallet.json
```

And to close a program, you can run:

```
solana program close --bypass-warning -k my_file_system_wallet.json <PROGRAM_ID>
```